# Setting font color of Icon View Options

Tags: macos, finder, dmg

While building a custom dmg 'drag installer', a question arose whether the font color of labels under the icons can be changed.

The information in here doesn't seem terribly positive - there is no such property in the "Icon View Options" object.

http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AppleScript/2.1/en/as2039.html

I wonder if anyone has managed to accomplish that feat? In any way other than embedding the text in the background itself?